# Generics in Object Pascal: types equality

Tags: generics, pascal, freepascal

I am trying to learn Object Pascal (maybe for hobby projects), and I found that Object Pascal (FreePascal) supports generics in `{$mode objfpc}`. They look like C# generics, but it seems as there is a difference. When I tried to declare a variable:

```pascal
uses Fgl;
...
SomeVariable: TFPSList<string>;
```

I've got error which said me about unexpected '<' and I removed parameter `<string>` and it passes compilation. So, seems that list of string's and list of int's would be declared in the same way: `Something: TFPSList`. But this means that Pascal treats both lists as of the same type, right? In C# and other languages type parameter modifies all type and creates new type. I know that old Pascales used containers of pointers as "generic" solution (`TList`, etc), but `TFPSList` is a real generic but in the declaration it looks like simple container of pointers. Does modern Pascal (FreePascal, Delphi) distinguish between these generic types (similar to `TFPSList` of int's/of string's)? If I have generic list of int's does it mean that I can pass it to the function expecting a list of another type and how/where I should check items type: compile time/runtime? I know about `is` and `as` keywords, but what to do if list is empty? How to check the type of container's items?

PS. Excuse me if the question sounds strange or stupid, I never used Pascal before.

Comment: Try using `TFPGList`. As per https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/current/rtl/fgl/tfpslist.html, `TFPSList` is a base class that _is not meant to be used directly_ (Note I haven't used either, I just googled 'TFPGList')

Comment: Some time with the documentation should clear up these misunderstandings quite quickly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in fgl unit TFPSList is not  a generic type, its a normal class so you can't specialize it,
use  TFPGList, your syntax is also wrong, in {$mode objfpc} you need to use **specialize** keyword for generic, the correct  syntax is :

```
program Project1;

     {$mode objfpc}
    uses Classes,sysutils,fgl;
    type
    SomeType=specialize TFPGList<String>;
     var
       SomeVariable:SomeType;
    begin
      SomeVariable:=SomeType.Create;
      SomeVariable.Add('some string');
    end.
```

free pascal also generic in Delphi mode {$MODE Delphi} with different syntax, more information here [free pascal doc](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refch8.html)